# How do you type 啼く in the Japanese IME

Tags: kanji

I have tried looking online and messing with the settings to get it to display 啼く yet I can't get it to, as far as I am aware you should have to type なく(naku) to get it to appear, yet it does not.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This type of question is off-topic for the main site.  Please refer to our [resources](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese) for help with IMEs.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using the Japanese Windows IME keyboard and the all Japanese language features installed through the Time & Language settings. With all that, you should be able to get 啼く easily by typing in なく when using the Japanese Windows IME keyboard in Hiragana mode.

After typing なく just press the spacebar a couple of times and this should bring up a list of possible word options. For me, 啼く came up as the 5th entry in the list. 啼く should be part of the standard integrated dictionary.

If it still does not come up for some reason you could always add the word to your personal dictionary as a work around. Although I would argue uninstalling and reinstalling the language pack would be a better first choice.

With that said, while I have no real experience doing this, you should be to do it by going to:

Settings -> Time & Language -> Language & Region -> The Language Options (triple ellipses button in the righthand corner) for Japanese (found in the Languages section) -> The Keyboard Options (triple ellipses button in the righthand corner) for Microsoft IME (found in the Keyboards section) -> Learning and Dictionary -> Open the user dictionary tool (a blue text link / button found in the  User Dictionary Section)

This should open a new window for your personal dictionary, which has an Add button (book with pencil icon) in the toolbar area. From here just fill out your entry as you see fit.

Just for further context, I'm using the Japanese Microsoft IME keyboard on Window's 11 with the default settings for everything.

Comment: I am missing the language and region tab

Comment: ah, I found the dictionary setting somehow

Comment: it worked, thanks